# Navigate to Page other than Deafult Page set in WMAppManifest.xml

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

As we all know we have to define default navigating page in `WMAppManifest` file. I've `MainPage.xaml` page as default, but I want to Navigate to some other Page on application launch. I do not want to remove MainPage from WMAppManifest file.

Currently I had tried the following things

- On MainPage loaded I'm navigating to the second Page.
- In App.xaml.cs I've set the following code in `CompleteInitializePhoneApplication` method

  ```
  RootFrame.Source = new Uri("/Songslist.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
  ```

Both are working but the app hangs for seconds during navigating which gives bad looks. I can't upload the sceenshot because it happens for seconds. How could I achieve this thing?
When I do with the following code I got NullReference Exception because RootVisual=null

```
    (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/Songslist.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: You can find three different solution in this question asked yesterday : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169657/how-to-change-start-page-at-startup/19170032?noredirect=1#comment28360898_19170032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should us an `UriMapper`, it will allow you to redirect the app to a specific page based on conditions. Here is how to do:

At the end of the Application constructor in the App.xaml.cs, set the `RootFrame.UriMapper` to a new `UriMapper` that does the redirection:

```
var mapper = new UriMapper();
string page = "/Songslist.xaml";

// Here you map "MainPage.xaml" to "Songslist.xaml"
mapper.UriMappings.Add(new UriMapping
{
    Uri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative),
    MappedUri = new Uri(page, UriKind.Relative)
});

this.RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;
```

The advantage is that it shouldn't hang anymore, and there won't be `MainPage.xaml` in the back stack.

Comment: You need to place it the App.xaml.cs file at the end of the Application constructor

Comment: Olivier its working but in between the app if i'm navigating to main page, it again redirecting me to songslist page. what is happening?

Comment: ok I'm resetting the urimapper to null on Songslist Constructor. its working now.

Comment: That's normal, the UriMapper indicates that every time you try to go to Page1.xaml, it should go to Page2.xaml.